# print the fileds which has a specific annotation in a Java class

Tags: java, jpa-2.0

In my model there are different  persistent fields which have different annotation such as @Column, @OneToMany ,  etc.

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "Clinte", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private Set<Takeover> takeovers = new HashSet<Takeover>();

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
@JoinColumn(name = "CAR_ID")
private Car carID;

@Column(length = 50, name = "TYPE")
private String type;
```

how can I print the persistent fields which has the annotation @Column and has the type String  ?? for example in the my code, i just want to print "type" as it has the annotation @Column and has the type String.

Comment: I'm not going to answer in detail, but I'll give you a place to look. The reflections library will allow you to get a list of all fields and inspect them for type and annotations (assume the annotations have run-time support: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/package-summary.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the way to do that:

```
        Field[] fields=myClass.class.getDeclaredFields();
      for (int i=0; i != fields.length; ++i) {
        Field field=fields[i];
        Column info=field.getAnnotation(Column.class);
        if (info == null || field.getType() != String.class){
               continue;
              }
        System.out.println("Field Name : "+  field.getName() + "  Field type: " +field.getType().getSimpleName());
      }
```